# How to redirect multiple folders to the reflecting subdomain with .htaccess

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, pcre

i tried redirecting some folders to the subdomains with the same names as the folders. I tried this way but it didn't work:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(test1|test2)(.*?)$ http://$1.domain.com$2 [R=301,L]`

I guess the problem is that the alternation of folders doesn't return a result that i can get into $1, right?

I'm not a PCRE expert so andy help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does mod_rewrite work at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/yoursub

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yoursub.domain.com/$1 [L]
```

The 2 lines in the middle will prevent redirecting if that folder or file exists.
To remove file and folder exception, comment out that 2 lines, and stay with this only:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/yoursub
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yoursub.domain.com/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Probably my question wasn't clear enough:

I want to redirect different folders to different subdomains. The subdomains have the same name as the folders and i'd like to have only one rewrite for all of them.

Example: /test -> test.domain.com
Example2: /dog -> dog.domain.com

Comment: why don't you configure out the apache insted of rewrite?
http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=23